# product of comprime numbers and UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

It is well-known that if a product of coprime numbers is a perfect square, so are the numbers. The proof depends on fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and this implies that in a UFD, if ab is a perfect square and a, b are coprime elements then a, b are perfect squares times a unit. My question is, does this hold in any integeral domain other than UFDs?

Comment: Maybe it's true in number fields with odd class number.

Comment: Maybe also in $K[x,y,z]/(xy-z^3)$, $K$ a field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true in any gcd domain, i.e. $\ (a,b)=1,\ \color{#c00}{ab = c^2}\Rightarrow\, (a) = (a,c)^2, $ since by basic gcd laws

$\quad(a,c)^2 = (a^2,\color{#c00}{c^2},ac) = (a^2,\color{#c00}{ab},ac) = (a)(a,b,c) = (a),\ $ by $\,(a,b,c)=1,\,$ by $\,(a,b)=1$

But there are gcd domains not UFDs, e.g. the ring of all algebraic integers, which is Bezout so gcd, but has no primes since every element factors $\,\alpha = \sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt{\alpha}$

Comment: In the ring of all algebraic integers, every element is a square, so that example is included in another answer.

Comment: @Gerry As I wrote, but the above answer shows more.

Comment: If R is a dedekind domain of the desired property, does it have to be a gcd domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in particular this holds in any ring where every element is a square.  For example, let $R$ be obtained from $\mathbb{Z}$ by repeatedly adjoining all possible square roots.  Then $R$ is not a UFD, but has the desired property.